# UICollectionView in UICollectionView reloadData on AppleTV

Tags: ios, swift, focus, tvos, apple-tv

I am developing appleTV application.

I have a `UICollectionView` inside a `UICollectionView cell`.

When the data is updated, the `CollectionView` placed in the `ViewController` is `reloadData`, and at the same time, the `CollectionView` in the `CollectionView` is also `reloadData`.

Then focus does not return to the original position in `CollectionView`.

The `CollectionView` placed in the `ViewController` is `canFocusItemAt` `false`.

What should I do?

```swift
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView === self.collectionView {
            return 10
        } else {
            return 10
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canFocusItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        if collectionView === self.collectionView {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView === self.collectionView {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "aaaa", for: indexPath)
            if let collectionView = cell.viewWithTag(20) as? UICollectionView {
                collectionView.delegate = self
                collectionView.dataSource = self
                collectionView.reloadData()
            }
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "bbbb", for: indexPath)
            return cell
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```